# How do I locate and loosen the rear derailleur hanger bolt?

Tags: derailleur

Context:

I need to remove my rear derailleur so that I can attach an alignment tool and straighten things out.

Images of the rear derailleur while the bike is upside-down:

- http://www.zooomr.com/z/photos/zoom/9626152/size-8/
- http://www.zooomr.com/z/photos/zoom/9626153/size-8/

Question:

Where is the derailleur's hanger's bolt that attaches the derailleur to the frame?

**Solution:**

1. Find a hex wrench with a long handle (at least as long as the 3-way hex wrench from Park Tools)
2. Turn counter-clockwise in the area circled in red by Jerry.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I've put a red circle around the hanger bolt.
[image]

Comment: I dearly wish I could upvote you and check the checkbox but I tried budging that with a 5mm hex key and it wouldn't budge, no matter how hard I tried.

Comment: @Zian: Look around the backside where the bolt comes out the other side of the hanger. A few drops of thin oil (and a 20 minute or so wait for it to penetrate) may help quite a bit.

Comment: This is probably not the best way to do it but I don't know a better way....1 vote (and checked answer) to Jerry for the oil advice & answering the original question. 1 real-life vote to my dad for findign a 5mm hex with a long handle. -1 to myself for trying to use a travel set of hex keys. :)

Answer (score 5):

Jerry Coffin has correctly displayed it.

You can also see it in the context of a bare frame. In the pictured Salsa Fargo, with a black removable derailleur hanger at the rear dropouts, you can see the projection that hangs down with a hole in it. That's what the hanger bolt screws into.

[image: Salsa fargo frame]